# How to create a vertical toolbar on the right side of the screen?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I would like to create a toolbar which have have some buttons in it which will do some actions but those actions do not involve navigation to other viewControllers.

I want to be able to show and hide that toolbar, but first how do I create one?

What are the options available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your day is going well. ^^

My thoughts are you can put a navigation button up on the top of the view, you can have it display the tool bar when you click on it and then in order to hide it you can just click the button again. Have the button say something like Display and after you click to display have it say hide so the user knows to click on it to hide it. This will be much easier if you have a navigationViewController.

Another option is a side table bar which you would swipe right to have it display and then left to hide it. Let the rows be selectable and give them function. This is a very neat and quite popular theme in apps today and in reality isn't to hard to do with all the guides you can find!

I wish you luck and I hope one of my ideas was to your liking!

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a UIView styled to look like a toolbar, you can then place various elements such as buttons onto it and pin it to the side of the screen with a constraint. Animate this constraint to move the toolbar on and off screen.